# ios: ScrollView + Container + PageViewController + TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, containers, uipageviewcontroller

I need to implement screen with image on top. And bellow I have 2 sections with tableView in each. Like that:

[image]

views hierarchy:

- scrollView

  - ContainerView

    - PageViewController

      - TableViewController

When I change segment, I update scrollView Size:

```
     var containerFrame = containerView.frame
    let tableView = [songsUserInterface, singersUserInterface][segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex].tableView!
    let tableViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
    let containerHeight = max(tableViewContentHeight, maxContainerHeight)
    containerFrame.size.height = containerHeight
     containerView.frame = containerFrame

    // Set content height of scrollview according to container
    var scrollFrame = scrollView.frame
    scrollFrame.size.height = containerFrame.origin.y + containerHeight
    //  + height of any other subviews below the container
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: containerFrame.origin.y + containerHeight)
```

And everything works fine except one thing: Paging by swipe(default for PageViewController) does not work in a blue area:

red - screen size

green - entire content size

blue - content size which hidden initially

[image]

Comment: The Red rectangle is the ScreenSize... is it *also* the frame of your ScrollView? Is the image a TableViewHeader? Or is it outside the ContainerView? Can you show a minimal *runnable* example?

Comment: solved. Issue was becaue I place SCroll view to another view. So, I need to increase height of that view as well

Comment: post as answer and then accept it so other will know whats the issue